# How to fetch thousands of data from database without getting slow down?

Tags: database, oracle, methodology

I want auto search option in textbox and data is fetching from database. I have thousands of data in my database table (almost 8-10000 rows). I know how to achieve this but as I am fetching thousands of data, it will take a lot of time to fetch. How to achieve this without getting slow down? Should I follow any other methodology to achieve this apart from simple fetching methods? I am using Oracle SQL Developer for database.

Comment: Are you already using `DISTINCT` ? Or you can simply `LIMIT` the number of the rows returned

Comment: Using auto search in a text box to query 10,000 rows doesn't seem like a good idea.  Does that mean that as soon as the user types a letter e.g. "a" you immediately display all rows that have an "a" in the column you are matching on, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious solutions involving indexes and caching, if this is web technology and depending on your tool you can sometimes set a minimum length before the server call is made. Here is a jquery UI example: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength

"The minimum number of characters a user must type before a search is performed. Zero is useful for local data with just a few items, but a higher value should be used when a single character search could match a few thousand items."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your web interface, but you can use two tecniques:

1. Paginate your data: if your requirements are to accept empty values and to show all the results load them in block of a predefined size. goggle for example paginates search results. On Oracle pagination is made using the rownum special variable (see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241622/paging-with-oracle)). Beware: you must first issue a query with a order by and then enclose it in a new one that use rownum. Other databases that use the limit keyword behave in a different way. If you apply the pagination techique to a drop down you end up with an infinite scroll (see [this respons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812758/jquery-smartautocomplete-with-infinite-scroll)e for example)
2. Limit you data imposing some filter that limits the number of rows returned; your search display some results only after the user typed at least n chars in the field

You can combine 1 & 2, but unless you find an existing web component (a jquery one for example) it may be a difficult task if you don't have a Javascript knowledge.